# Is there an inexpensive multi-pole, multi-position relay?

Tags: transistors, relay

One of my projects consist of being able to redirect audio output from one among several PCs to one among several audio devices such as headsets, speakers or audio recording devices. The redirector can link only one input to one output. For instance, audio from PC 1 can go to the headset, or audio from PC 2 can go to the speakers.

The essential characteristic is that when a link from input to output is removed, all three connections (GND, left channel, right channel) should be cut, and only then new link should be eventually established. In other words, I don't want, for instance, the GND of multiple input devices to be wired together.

This can relatively easy be done with two rotary switches. A 3-pole, N-position rotary switch will make it possible to establish a connection with an input or output device and break the connection with GND and both channels at the same time.

However, how is it possible to do inexpensively if I want to be able to switch from a device to another not by manually turning a knob, but by sending a signal to an electronic device (for instance with an Arduino)? From what I can find, there are DPDT relays and even 3PDT relays, although they don't seem quite common, but triple pole triple throw ones don't exist, or at least I haven't found them. I suppose, therefore, that the problem like that is not solved with 3P3T or 3P4T relays, but something else.

What exactly are the options?

Combining multiple relays is possible (and eventually any configuration could be achieved by SPDT relays assembled in a form of three parallel trees), but this seems overly complex and quite expensive.

Should I use a series of bipolar junction transistors for that? Or something else?

Comment: You can set up a bank of relays and just operate them one at a time. There are ICs for this, but they impose complications and that would require discussion and some work on our part. So, for now, the easier solution for all concerned is a lot of DPDT relays controlled by transistors controlled by your Arduino. Of course, you may find the rotary switch cheaper, then, too. By comparison.

Comment: any DPST relays with SPST reed relay for grounds is lowest cost and arrange as a crosspoint switch from all sources to all loads. X to Y with suitable dead time

Comment: @jonk: it seems that this is indeed my only option. Could you please promote your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko You don't need large relays, so likely the smaller the better. But I still have a question. You may also wish to use latching relays, because they don't require power all the time. You just switch them with a pulse and then move on. When you are finished switching things around, no more power is consumed and that's usually considered a "good thing." You could even turn off the Arduino and they'd still leave the connection in place. But the problem appears to be that they are about twice as expensive. So using them will double your costs. Are you okay with increased cost?

Comment: @jonk: latching relays are indeed a better option here.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko Okay. I'll suggest something then. You'll need three relays per device (in or out) and they will be a few dollars each. Multiply it out by all of your devices that need to be cross-connected to work out how many relays are required and then multiply that by about US$2 or so to figure your cost in relays alone. The rest will be cheap. But that's what you are looking at for the base cost of the system. I'll suppose you can handle all the wiring. Hopefully, you live in a small home!